# Find $g(x)$ midpoint

Tags: analytic-geometry, average

How can we find a function $g(x)$ such that, for any given value of $x$, the point $(x, g(x))$ is the arithmetic average of some two points on the graph of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, where the distance between these two points is exactly $1$?

At first, I attempted to approach the problem by creating a circle with a center at $(x, \frac{1}{x})$ and a radius of $1$, hoping to find the intersection point. However, this approach quickly became overly complicated.

For example: for the point $(a, f(a))$, I derived the following equations: $(x - a)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{a}\right)^2 = 1$. Unfortunately, due to the nature of these equations (4th degree), expressing $x$ in terms of $a$ is chanalging.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math3.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: ok got you,  i added a clue.

Comment: That's a great start, and it's how I would proceed. Can you share the results of that, even if it's excessively complex?

Comment: For the point (a, f(a)), I obtained the following equations: (x - a)^2 + (1/x - 1/a)^2 = 1. However, due to the nature of these equations (4th degree), I was unable to express x in terms of a.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you edit that into the post, else it will be closed for not showing your work. I also encourage you to expand/show the 4th degree, and explain why you can't do much with it. $\quad$ FWIW Just because a question can be asked, doesn't necessarily mean that it has a nice answer.

Comment: ok got you, i edit the post.

Comment: Sorry, my 1st link should have been https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(a,1/a)$ and $(b,1/b)$ be two points on the graph of $f(x)=1/x$ such that the distance between them is $1$. Then
$$
(a-b)^2+\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)^2=1. \tag{1}
$$
If $(x,y)$ is the arithmetic average of those points, then
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\frac{a+b}{2}, \\
y=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)=\frac{x}{ab},
\end{cases} 
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
a+b=2x, \\
ab=\frac{x}{y}. \tag{2}
\end{cases}
$$
Let's now rewrite $(1)$ in terms of $a+b$ and $ab$:
\begin{align}
(1)\implies&(a-b)^2\left(1+\frac{1}{a^2b^2}\right)=1 \\
\implies& [(a+b)^2-4ab]\left(1+\frac{1}{a^2b^2}\right)=1 \\
\overset{(2)}{\implies}&\left(4x^2-\frac{4x}{y}\right)\left(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)=1 \\
\implies&\left(1-\frac{1}{xy}\right)\left(x^2+y^2\right)=\frac{1}{4}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Eq. $(3)$ defines implicitly the function $y=g(x)$ with the desired property.

Comment: Thank you.
And if we repeat this process and try to find g2(x) with the same property(relative to g(x) instead of f(x)) 
can it be easily done?
and in general finding g_k(x) with the same property(relative to g_(k-1)(x) instead of f(x))?

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with $(x - a)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{a}\right)^2 = 1$ we multiply both sides by $(\frac1x + \frac1a)^2$ to give us $$(\frac1x + \frac1a)^2(x-a)^2+\frac1{x^2} + \frac1{a^2} = \frac1{x^2}+ \frac1{a^2} + \frac2{ax}$$ so $$((\frac1x + \frac1a)(x-a))^2 = (\frac xa -\frac ax)^2=(\frac xa)^2-(\frac ax)^2 - \frac{x^2-a^2}{ax}=\frac2{ax}$$ then we multiply by $ax^2$ to clear denominators and get $$\frac{x^4}a - a^3-x^3-a^2x=2x$$ and so rearranging gives us $$\frac {x^4}a - x^3 -(2+a^2)x-a^3=0$$

and we have our quartic.

Comment: Thank you. And if we repeat this process and try to find g2(x) with the same property(relative to g(x) instead of f(x)) can it be easily done? and in general finding g_k(x) with the same property(relative to g_(k-1)(x) instead of f(x))?

Comment: I think your first expansion is incorrect. The second term should be $(1/x^2 - 1/a^2)^2$, not $1/x^2 + 1/a^2$